# What are the different purpose of "new" is available in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop

Can any one explain in the detail(with example) the different purpose of the "new" in C#.

Comment: Please leave "C#:" out of the title - just leave it in the tags. Also, please leave out "Hi" and "Thanks".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Object instantiation
2. In [anonymous types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx)
3. To signal that a member of the base class is being hidden.
4. As a [constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx)

About 3 ([from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx)):

```
public class BaseC
{
    public int x;
    public void Invoke() { }
}
public class DerivedC : BaseC
{
    new public void Invoke() { }
}
```

The keyowrd is not necessary but should be used to make it clear that the base-class constructor is being hidden.

Comment: Thanks for answer, can you explain new being hidden with explain , that would be very helpful for me. Thanks vijendra

Comment: Added the example from MSDN and the link to it.

Answer (score 7):

You have:

- [new operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa0ab757.aspx):

> Used to create objects and invoke
>   constructors

- [new modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx)

> When used as a modifier, the new
>   keyword explicitly hides a member
>   inherited from a base class

- [new constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx)

> The new constraint specifies that any
>   type argument in a generic class
>   declaration must have a public
>   parameterless constructor